# Glass Mapper BeginRenderLink produces link to www.google.com

Tags: glass-mapper

Sitecore 8.1 Revision 160519
Glass Mapper 4.5.0.4

I have a link field in Sitecore set to an internal link. If I just render the link on a page (link.GetUrl()) it produces the correct relative Url. But when I render the link using Glass Mapper it gives me a link to www.google.com.

```
using (BeginRenderLink(l => button.Destination, new { @class = "home-banner-rotator__btn" }, isEditable: true))
{
    @button.LinkTitle
}
```

Produces:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="home-banner-rotator__btn" tabindex="-1">View Restaurants</a>
```

I have confirmed that all items are published appropriately. I can call the item with the ItemService API and get the correct results:

https://mywebsite.com/sitecore/api/ssc/item/C36466E3-82D9-46F8-BC35-B4162BE1C94F?database=web

```
{
    "ItemID":"c36466e3-82d9-46f8-bc35-b4162be1c94f",
    "ItemName":"Dining",
    "ItemPath":"/sitecore/content/MySite/Content/Home Page Banner Content/Home Page Banner CTA Buttons/Dining",
    "ParentID":"b67ae0ec-1371-4d5f-879d-13dd47d38677",
    "TemplateID":"fd394012-6054-4d52-a18a-886ec2bb631c",
    "TemplateName":"MySite Home Page Banner CTA Button",  
    "CloneSource":null,
    "ItemLanguage":"en",
    "ItemVersion":"1",
    "DisplayName":"Dining",
    "HasChildren":"False",
    "ItemIcon":"/temp/iconcache/applications/32x32/document.png",
    "ItemMedialUrl":"/temp/iconcache/applications/48x48/document.png",
    "ItemUrl":"~/link.aspx?_id=C36466E382D946F8BC35B4162BE1C94F&amp;_z=z",
    "LinkTitle":"View Restaurants",
    "Destination":"<link text=\"Dining\" linktype=\"internal\" class=\"\" title=\"Dining\" target=\"\" querystring=\"\" id=\"{30DDCC76-4B18-4AFA-9242-90F248254251}\" />"
}
```

Never the less, the link is routinely rendered to www.google.com no matter what.

Comment: Closing. Question resolution was specific to the implementation and unlikely to provide value in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an issue of scope. The BeginRenderLink was inside a forloop so Glass misinterpreted what Item to use. It was using some item that had www.google.com as the url address. I couldnt figure out what item. To fix, I explicitly stated the item in my BeginRenderLink Html helper:

```
Html.Glass().BeginRenderLink(MyExplicityItemHere,m => m.Destination,etc...
```